# How to whitelist all scripts on a site with NoScript

Tags: firefox, noscript

How do you make the Firefox NoScript extension allow **all** scripts used on a specific site?

There's a misnamed/buggy "Allow all this page" option, but it doesn't actually allow everything. It seems to only allow all scripts **if they're served from the same domain**, but anything else (e.g. cloudfront, google-analytics, etc) still get blocked. This often breaks the site, and makes NoScript unusable, since a lot of benign sites use a lot of off-domain includes for various media. Some sites have dozens of scripts, and naturally NoScript reloads the page each time you white-list something, so it can take a several minutes to get the site working.

Is there a way around this hassle, or is it simpler to just uninstall NoScript and/or use a better designed Javascript-blocker?

Answer (score 4):

"Allow all this page" allows all the scripts that the current page refferences (from any domain). The gottcha is that those scripts may add refferences to additional domains that are still blocked. The site may also refference scripts on additional domains on other pages that you may navigate later. You may have to "Allow all this page" several times on the same site before all the scripts the site uses are unblocked.

NoScript is quite flexible in what it blocks, but it can take quite a bit of effort to get the results you're looking for. The inconvienience is directly related to the security that NoScript provides. If you want site specific javascript blocking, but don't want to set up the rules yourself, you could look for whitelists to import into NoScript (of course this is delegating your decision to trust a site to the source of the whitelist).

Comment: I now use uMatix which provides much more fexibility that NoScript did.

Answer (score 2):

Btw., [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sx4t.jpg) is a simple way to add one of those *pesky* domains, which feature a list of subdomains:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sx4t.jpg

(By **manually** adding the root domain :))

Same screenshots, as above, added to superuser:

[image: NoScript_1_of_5]

[image: NoScript_2_of_5]

[image: NoScript_3_of_5]

[image: NoScript_4_of_5]

[image: NoScript_5_of_5]

Answer (score 1):

NoScript Appearance Options control what's shown in its Toolbar icon menu, where *Allow all this page* & *Temporarily allow all this page* are both enabled by default. However, once you use the 'permanent' *Allow*, it'll fill-up the **Whitelist** quite-quickly and this may have an impact on performance (depending on RAM, even CPU). Keeping it unchecked - together with *Make page permission permanent*, prevents it getting used by accident:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/voO4tp7.png]

*Temporarily allow all this page* can easily be invoked, by setting keyboard shortcuts as it is outlined in the [InformAction faq](https://noscript.net/faq#qa3_11); **and** simply by using middle-click on the toolbar button to let all scripts run temporarily.

Btw., there had been an issue which was repaired, some versions back, [noscript.key.revokeTemp shortcut not working.](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=21077)

^^ Similary to adding the keyboard shortcuts through Firefox *about:config*, there is **blacklist** of Untrusted domains, which is under the setting: **noscript.untrusted**