# NoScript and sites with lots of JavaScript per page

Tags: firefox, noscript

For web browsing, I use Firefox and NoScript. One thing that irritates me is sites that expect to load another set of capabilities every time I change pages.

Particularly annoying are shopping sites that only load payment Javascript when ‘Pay Now’ is clicked. I often end up having to do the whole thing more than once, as clicking Temporarily Trusted restarts the transaction. Of course, every site seems to use a different provider, so Trusted is of limited value. I am trying to avoid the habit of clicking Allow All all the time.

The How-to at https://proprivacy.com/adblocker/guides/noscript-extension-gain-privacy-security acknowledges the problem, but only suggests trial and error. Surely, we as super users can do better.

Does anyone have any hints for making this process less of a hassle?

[How to whitelist all scripts on a site with NoScript](https://superuser.com/questions/781609/how-to-whitelist-all-scripts-on-a-site-with-noscript) refers, but does not help.

Comment: There is no way to predict/know what a site will try to load. It could change at any time, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use an add-on with finer granularity, such as [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/ublock-origin/), which allow sites to be blocked or white-listed, and can block particular elements, such as JavaScript (shown below), remote fonts or large media elements *per* site. *[uBlock Origin* even has the ability to block user-selected *static elements*, such as obnoxious YouTube overlays.

[image: uBlock Origin, JavaScript]